# prolog: logic programming

Tags: prolog

How do I write Prolog code that picks out only numbers out of a list containing numbers and letters? For example, if I have [a,b,7,d,3,e,f,5], I want to write code that gives me [7,3,5].
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313626/write-a-prolog-program-displaying-an-mn-grid-of-asterisk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a function that gives you back a list. There is no such thing as a return statement in Prolog, but you can use parameters to specify out-things as well.

```
% The second parameter will be our OUT parameter.
% It can be anything that we specify.

% Return an empty list, because our input is empty as well
numFilter([],[]).

% return a list with H and what will come out recursively
numFilter([H|T],[H|T2]) :- number(H), numFilter(T,T2).

% return a list with what will come out recursively. H is not a number
numFilter([H|T],T2) :- not(number(H)), numFilter(T,T2).
```

So you specify rules for every kind of input that can happen to you. We have one for an empty list, and we have two for a list that has at least one element. The first element will be checked and we continue with this recursively.

We can call this function with a call like this:

```
numFilter([a,b,7,d,3,e,f,5],A).
```

The A is a variable that will be filled in by prolog at runtime.
`number: 1` is a function that is in the [prolog dictionary](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#number).

So for these kind of assignments, you need recursion for your lists. Remember that.

Comment: ok. thanks, what if the list is a nested list, like let say for instance you have something like this ([a,b,1,[2,[c,3]],d],1,A), and i want to get this [2,3].

Comment: @guest Then you will need to have another rule that checks if the H is a list. If so, you can do a `numFilter` on H as well and append the results. Like: `numFilter([[H|Tinner]|T],[T2|T3]) :- numFilter([H|Tinner],T2), numFilter(T,T3).` We now know that it is a list with at least one element.

Answer (score 3):

its easy to put this into a findall:

```
numList(ListIn, Nums) :-
  findall(H, (member(H, ListIn), number(H)), Nums).
```

query with:

```
?- numList([a,b,7,d,3,e,f,5], Nums).
Nums = [7, 3, 5].
```

prolog's findall is really fantastically useful!

Comment: There are more specific library predicates for this use case, for example: include(number, List0, List).