# write a prolog program displaying an M*N grid of asterisk?

Tags: prolog

I need to write a recursive predicate `rectangle`, such that `rectangle(M, N)` writes out a solid rectangle of size `M x N` of asterisks, i.e., there should be `M` rows and `N` columns in the rectangle. For example:

```
?- rectangle(3,8).
********
********
********
true
```

So far I have the statement `line` that prints `N` asterisks on a line:

```
line(0).
line(N) :- write('*'), A is N-1 , line(A).
```

I've tried everything, but I keep getting an infinite grid of asterisks. Here's what I've got so far:

```
rectangle(0,0).
rectangle(M,N) :-
    line(M),
    write('*'), nl, A is N-1, line(A-1),
    rectangle(M,A).
```

Comment: It's good that you've tried everything, but it will be easier to help you if you show us what you've tried.

Comment: what I've got so far is: rectangle(0,0).
rectangle(M,N) :- line(M),
    write('*'), nl, A is N-1, line(A-1). it just displays an infinite amount of asterisks. thanks

Comment: why do you pass M to line, when it seems that M is the number of rows, not of columns? Why do you call line twice? why do you write an asterix? can you actually write down the logic of your program in normal words, not prolog? it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know your assignment requires a recursive procedure, then you should not consider this as an answer. But I'd like to show a possible concise solution, using a metapredicate:

```
loop_n(P, N) :- forall(between(1, N, _), P).
rectangle(R, C) :- loop_n((loop_n(write(*), C), nl), R).
```

Not every Prolog support calling a variable. In my old Prolog interpreter, for instance, I'd write `loop_n(P, N) :- forall(between(1, N, _), call(P)).`

Answer (score 0):

Getting an infinite grid of asterisks is because you haven't defined rectangle(M,0).
So, the code should be as follows:

```
rectangle(0,0).
rectangle(M,0).
rectangle(M,N) :-
    line(M),nl, A is N-1, rectangle(M,A).
line(0).
line(B) :- write('*'), Z is B-1 , line(Z).
```